# figure caption on sjPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

Does anyone know how to add a figure caption using sjPlot?

This is the code I have and I've tried multiple ways to add a figure caption, but has not been successful.

plot_model(mm1,type="pred", title = "Random Intercept and Fixed Slope",
terms=c("l.carb","mfr"), pred.type="re")

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As the object created by `sjPlot::plot_model()` is a `ggproto` object, you can interact with the output the same as if you made a plot using `ggplot()`.  Use `labs()` and reference `caption=`.  Note that you can also use this to overwrite any of the existing labels created by `plot_model()` (like the title, axis labels, etc...).

Here, I modified the [first example shown on the sjPlot reference](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html).

```
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)
m <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code, data = efc)

# simple forest plot
p <- plot_model(m)


p + labs(caption='This is my caption')
```

[image]